The meaning of linear transformation in a batch norm revisited
I'm reading BatchNorm Wikipedia page, where they explain that BatchNorm.
I think the actual formulas are easier than words in this case. The norm statistics are calculated as:
$$\large{\displaystyle \mu _{B}={\frac {1}{m}}\sum _{i=1}^{m}x_{i}}$$
$$\large{\displaystyle \sigma _{B}^{2}={\frac {1}{m}}\sum _{i=1}^{m}(x_{i}-\mu _{B})^{2}}$$
Note that the mean is taking a specific column, here a dimension of the input vector, and doing that for the $m$ samples i.e in standard DL this is just a column of the input matrix.
The correction formula is:
$$\large{\displaystyle {\hat {x}}_{i}^{(k)}={\frac {x_{i}^{(k)}-\mu _{B}^{(k)}}{\sqrt {\left(\sigma _{B}^{(k)}\right)^{2}+\epsilon }}}}$$
$k$ is $k$-th column, $i$ is $i$-th row.
I have read a similar question here.
I think though that $\gamma$ not a single number, but a number for each column, this in turn can be thought as a diagonal matrix. (see formula below.)
So the interpretation of the formula, rather than what is given in the answer to the linked question above, is that it "tidies" the values down each column, but allows each row's components to keep a numerical relevance to one another.
$$\large{\displaystyle y_{i}^{(k)}=\gamma ^{(k)}{\hat {x}}_{i}^{(k)}+\beta ^{(k)}}$$
It seems to me that when one assumes this, the meaning of the linear transform becomes clear: it restores (to some extent) a ratio between components in a row.
Is this reasoning correct?

Introduction
I think your reasoning regarding the interpretation of the linear transformation in batch normalisation (BatchNorm) is generally correct. Let's break it down to clarify the concepts:
Batch Normalisation Formulas
The normalisation process in BatchNorm involves calculating the mean and variance for each mini-batch as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_B &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i \\
\sigma_B^2 &= \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m} (x_i - \mu_B)^2
\end{align}
$$
where $m$ is the number of samples in the mini-batch.
The normalised value for each input $x_i^{(k)}$ is then calculated as:
$$
\hat{x}_i^{(k)} = \frac{x_i^{(k)} - \mu_B^{(k)}}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^{(k)^2} + \epsilon}}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small constant added for numerical stability.
Importance of Batch Normalisation
Batch normalisation is important because it stabilises and accelerates the training process by reducing internal covariate shift. This means that it helps in maintaining a consistent distribution of inputs to each layer, which in turn improves the convergence rate of the neural network.
Affine Transformation Post-Normalisation:
After normalisation, BatchNorm applies an affine transformation to restore the expressive power of the network:
$$
y_i^{(k)} = \gamma^{(k)} \hat{x}_i^{(k)} + \beta^{(k)}
$$
Here, $\gamma^{(k)}$ and $\beta^{(k)}$ are learnable parameters for each feature dimension $k$. These parameters allow the model to scale and shift the normalised values.
Purpose and Interpretation:
The primary purpose of BatchNorm is to standardise the features, ensuring that they have a mean of 0 and variance of 1. This standardisation helps speed up training and improve convergence. However, without the affine transformation, normalisation alone could limit the representational capacity of the network. The affine transformation with $\gamma$ and $\beta$ reintroduces the ability to adjust the normalised features, preserving the network's expressive power.
Maintaining Expressive Power:
Your reasoning that $\gamma$ and $\beta$ can be thought of as maintaining the numerical relevance between components in a row is correct. The affine transformation post-normalisation ensures that the ratios between different components are maintained, allowing the network to retain its capacity to model complex functions effectively. This mechanism helps prevent over-normalisation, which could strip the network of its ability to learn diverse features.
Conclusion:
In conclusion, BatchNorm not only standardises the input features but, through the affine transformation, maintains the network's expressive power. The learnable parameters $\gamma$ and $\beta$ ensure that the network can still capture complex patterns by adjusting the normalised values appropriately.
